# Populate values of inline multidate Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm new to JavaScript and still kind of new web development in general so I may be off in my understanding here somewhere.

Here goes:
In an *ASP.NET MVC* project with *Entity Framework* and *Razor*.

I'm using the [**bootstrap datepicker**](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to try to create an inline multidate selector. I use a hidden input field to capture the list of dates from the datepicker as follows *(note: the reason I'm using a hidden input field here is because I don't want to show a textbox, only the inline datepicker. However, I can't get the DatePicker to both appear inline and also use an input div to capture the multidate string.)*:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker datepicker-inline" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenForDates" value="@Model.SelectedDateString" name='@Html.NameFor(model => model.SelectedDateString)'/>
```

Then some script to tie it in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        multidate: true,
        inline: true
    });

    $('#datepicker').on("changeDate", function () {
        $('#hiddenForDates').val(
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'))
    });
});
```

The HTML input captures the string of dates from the `datepicker` (like "01/01/2016, 01/02/2015"...). Then in the script I'm setting up the `DatePicker` and when the `changeDate` event occurs, updating the value in the input to the string of dates.

The problem I'm having is when loading the page, I want the `DatePicker` to seed with the value from the input (right now it seems to populate one way). When my page loads, the hidden input contains the string of dates but the `datepicker` has no dates selected.

I've tried `setDates` and `setUTCDates` per the documentation but that doesn't seem to help (my value is a string of comma separated values, but even if I build an array of Dates it doesn't make a difference).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

*Note: I should also point out that I have been able to get this to work using:*

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDateString, new{ @class = form-control datepicker})`

*but this does not allow me to use an inline datepicker.*

Comment: try changing the datePicker div into an input with the same value as the hidden one <inpupt value="@Model.SelectedDateString" id="datepicker" class="datepicker datepicker-inline" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"/>

Comment: @LiviuBoboia Thanks for the suggestion. However, I've set it up this way because I haven't been able to find any other way to both show the datepicker inline and hide the textbox. If I change the DatePicker div to an input then I can't do both show the picker and hide the textbox.